# как избежать повторение стилей после импорта и как добиться эффекта слияния текста с картинкой

Tags: css, reactjs, scss

или при импорте глобального scss файла в разные модульные scss или же из за того что модульные scss импортируются в компоненты в браузере каждый стиль написанный в глобальном применяется столько раз сколько раз был импортирован в другие scss

https://armensargsyan1993.github.io/global-react-app-cosmo/#/about

**насчет эффекта он в page about**

сам же написал но не понял как так получилось может дело в картинке

Comment: **по поводу слияния текста с картинкой**: там просто `.png` изображение, которое ложиться на обычный текст и создает такой эффект. это не заслуга `css`

Comment: **по поводу повторения стилей**: а зачем вы импортируете глобальные/общие стили в каждый модуль? это уже неправильно. модульный `css` как раз и должен быть независим от других стилей. если же вы нуждались в *миксинах* или *переменных*, то проще всего **именно их вынести в отдельный файл** и **только их отдельно импортировать** в каждый модуль